# Отключить 1 ядро

Tags: windows, bat, cmd

Надо на .bat написать скрипт отключающий 1 ядро для процеса.

Answer (score 1):

Можно установить Process Affinity для выбранного процесса ([Set Processor Affinity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759098(v=ws.10).aspx)). Для IIS есть утилита Adsutil.vbs (`%SystemDrive%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\`)

```
cscript adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/AppPools/[приложение]/SMPAffinitized TRUE
cscript adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/AppPools/[пула приложений]/SMPProcessorAffinityMask [маска]
```